# Why do I need main method if I develop web app as war using Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am developing web app using Spring Boot. My typical deployment is generating `war` and place it in `webapps` folder in Tomcat directory.

I noticed with [SpringBoot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file), I will need a `main` method. I am wondering why this is needed. If there is a way to avoid it, what would that be?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think you need a main method if you want to deploy as war. What happens if you remove it?

Comment: Yeah, you don't need it. You can just remove it if it is only ever just a WAR file you are building.

Comment: The crucial part of the documentations is "(...) you *update* your application’s main class to extend SpringBootServletInitializer"; if you search the rest of that page for occurrences of "`public class Application`" you'll see that they simply refer to the previous shape of that class.

Comment: @JBNizet: the build fails if I remove main method. I have a post here on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831953/maven-build-failing-when-generating-war-package-for-spring-boot-application

Comment: @rhinds. without main method, build is failing.  please see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831953/maven-build-failing-when-generating-war-package-for-spring-boot-application

Comment: @kryger: please see my comment above

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Main method is not required for the typical deployment scenario of building a war and placing it in webapps folder of Tomcat. All you need is:

```
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

However, if you want to be able to launch the app from within an IDE (e.g. with Eclipse's Run As -> Java Application) while developing or [build  an executable jar or a war](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging) that can run standalone with Spring Boot's embedded tomcat by just `java -jar myapp.war` command, an entry point class with a main method might be helpful.

Comment: +1. thanks for the info. btw what does `application.sources(Application.class)` do? what is its sole purpose? Is it necessary or can it be avoided?

Comment: As per the [JavaDoc of the method](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.html#sources(java.lang.Class...)), it adds more sources (configuration classes and components) for Spring to scan for context initialisation of this application.

Comment: I tried without main method and it is failing: Here it is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831953/maven-build-failing-when-generating-war-package-for-spring-boot-application?noredirect=1#comment47793253_29831953

Answer (score 5):

**To run in a separate web container**

You don't need the main method, all you need is to do is to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` as *Kryger* mentioned.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
....
....
```

**To run in the command line as a standalone application**

Here you need the main method, so that you can run it using `java -jar` from the command line.

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
....
....
```

Source: https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/

Comment: This does not work: please see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831953/maven-build-failing-when-generating-war-package-for-spring-boot-application?noredirect=1#comment47793253_29831953

Comment: in version 3.8.3, what is the alternative to SpringBootServletInitializer?

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Boot one will basically need three things :

1) use the @SpringBootApplication annotation

2) extend SpringBootServletInitializer

3) overwrite the configure method as shown above

and that's it !