# maven build failing when generating war package for spring boot application?

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

This is an extension to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782148/why-do-i-need-main-method-if-i-develop-web-app-as-war-using-spring-boot) at SO. As per this post, main method is NOT required to generate a `deployable war`

I am trying to generate a `deployable war` for this simple application of [uploading files](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/). The source code can be for this example application can be found [here](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-uploading-files/tree/master/complete).

Following the instructions from spring boot for jar to war conversion, I changed my `pom.xml` to reflect the following. (Just added `tomcat` dependency with scope `provided`).

Reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-uploading-files</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Then I changed `Application.java` as follows

Reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    /*public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    } */
}
```

I tried two scenarios. both fail with the following error (`Unable to find main class`).

1. No main method (NOTE I have commented out main method above)
2. No application.Java file (commented out everything from this file - not shown here)

Error:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.218s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Apr 23 11:46:24 PDT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/222M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.3.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project gs-uploading-files: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.3.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find main class -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

**PS: when I have main method intact, the build is successful**

Comment: Any chance you still have a reference to your main class in the pom.xml?

Comment: @ci_: I am not sure what you mean exactly. I have updated with my entire pom.xml

Comment: Other than the answers to your linked question, I couldn't find any evidence that you can omit the main class, i.e. a class with main method. The spring-boot-maven-plugin seems to be looking for it. Maybe if you didn't use the plugin, but not sure if that's worth it.

Comment: If you only want to run the application as a standard war file, you could either remove the Boot plugin entirely or reconfigure it so that the repackage goal isn't bound to Maven's lifecycle

Comment: for testing locally, I would prefer embedded Tomcat. but for deployment, I will need war. I am not sure how can I get both the benefits here

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to get **both** the benefits - i.e. standalone executable war with embedded Tomcat *and* the normal war deployable in external Tomcat - you need to have a class with main method. So,

- Enable the main() method in your Application.java.
- Configure `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to specify the class with the main class (Spring should find it anyway if you have one, but good to be explicit I guess):

  `<plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
      <configuration>
          <mainClass>the.package.of.Application</mainClass>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
          <execution>
              <goals>
                  <goal>repackage</goal>
              </goals>
          </execution>
      </executions>
  </plugin>`
- Remove `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency in your pom with `provided` scope. Spring boot magically knows how to enable/disable embedded Tomcat.

With this you should be able to launch your Spring app from IDE by just running the Application.java class as a normal Java app, build a war file that is both standalone executable and deployable in external Tomcat as usual too.

I am currently building REST APIs with Spring Boot 1.0.1.RELEASE with this kind of setup and it works great in all three modes.

Comment: even without configuring spring-boot-maven-plugin (as you suggested), if I have main method, It works fine with both embedded and deployment war. If I want to enable only deployment war mode, it seems I need to still have `main`. Otherwise I cannot get it working.

Comment: Thats right, [as the document says](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging) if you don’t specify a main class the plugin will search for a class with a public static void main(String[] args) method. I personally prefer to specify the class explicitly though, for readability. But yeah, it is not required to be specified explicitly. 
If you want to enable deployment only in normal war mode, you don't need to use `spring-boot-maven-plugin` at all in your pom.

Comment: Thanks, In production, I doubt any body uses embedded Tomcat server. so, I would prefer `war` to be deployed. is removing `spring-boot-maven-plugin`, do I only get rid of `main method` search or something important is lost too?

Comment: True. Embedded Tomcat is more for easy distribution (e.g. your testers won't need any Tomcat installation first) and deployment while under development and testing. In production the usual war should be used. Removal of the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` and the main method should only take away the standalone executable/embedded Tomcat feature from war, nothing else (just tested this on my application and worked fine :))

Comment: If you have a choice, deploying an executable war or jar is the recommended approach.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson: why do you say embedded tomcat (executable jar) is recommend approach?

Answer (score 4):

Note that one can get a somewhat similar message along the lines of

---

Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.2.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project Xyz: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.2.RELEASE:repackage failed: **Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates** [com.a.Application, com.a.fake.Application, com.a.main.Main1, com.a.runner.DataImportRunner, com.a.temp.dependencyinjection.MainApp, com.a.finalapp.facade.impl.V3DataImports, com.a.finalapp.service.impl.App2]

---

(Which I saw in my application when attempting to run a Maven Install)

In my case, I had multiple main methods and Spring could not automatically choose the one I wanted.

The solution is the same outlined earlier by Naymesh Mistry (explicitly specify your.main.class.with.package.prefix in pom.xml)